# S3 get object not responding

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a lambda function in place which is connected to API Gateway. The lambda function fetches a file from S3. But Somehow, I am not getting any response from S3 & the API Gateway request is timing out. Can you please help me understand the issue here?

> The file I am trying to read is just of 20B in size

Code:-

```
 ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
 clientConfiguration.setMaxErrorRetry(5);
 clientConfiguration.setSocketTimeout(5000);
 AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                        .withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration)
                        .withRegion("us-east-2")
                        .enableForceGlobalBucketAccess()
                        .build();
final GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(<bucketName>, <objectKey>);
log.info("Get object from bucket {}", getObjectRequest);
S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest);
```

Nothing happens after: `s3Client.getObject()`

I have tried exception handling, Verified the bucket name, key & region. Provided the necessary permissions to s3 & lambda. Not sure what else is wrong.

Comment: What do CloudWatch Logs tell you? Perhaps this is as simple as the object being large so takes a long time to download and the Lambda function timeout is too low.

Comment: Yeah so, the object size is `20B` and the API Gateway timeout is 29 seconds. Also, I am not getting any logs after getObject()

Comment: There are final CloudWatch Logs beginning with "END" and "REPORT". Please include (ideally all of) the CW logs in your post but remove any sensitive info. What does your code do after the call to getObject? You should ideally include all the relevant code, not just the fragment shown.

Comment: The first thing to determine is if the Lambda function invocation timed out. You will see this in the CW logs. That's commonly caused by a networking misconfiguration where the Lambda function cannot reach an external endpoint, in this case the S3 service endpoint. The typical cause is connecting the Lambda function to a VPC but mis-configuring things.

Comment: Also it will be easy to debug if you can add the complete Lambda Code to understand what you trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not best practice. You are using Java V1 - not the recommended V2 version. You can read S3 objects from a Lambda function that is invoked by API Gateway. There is a full serverless tutorial that shows this use case in the [AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html). It uses AWS SDK for Java V2.

Look at that code:

[Create a photo asset management application that lets users manage photos using labels](https://%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_cross_PAM_section.html)

Also - when running AWS Java code in a Lambda function, you do not need to specify credentials to use AWS Services. Instead - you run the Lambda function using a role that has permission to invoke the specific AWS Service.

Here is part of the code that reads an object in a S3 bucket and returns a byte[].

```
public class S3Service {
    // Create the S3Client object.
    private S3Client getClient() {
        return S3Client.builder()
            .region(PhotoApplicationResources.REGION)
            .build();
    }

    public byte[] getObjectBytes(String bucketName, String keyName) {
        S3Client s3 = getClient();
        try {
            GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest
                .builder()
                .key(keyName)
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build();

            ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> objectBytes = s3.getObjectAsBytes(objectRequest);
            return objectBytes.asByteArray();
        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, what would be the recommended approach when we want to convert it into string?